# Android.bp and ninja: error: unknown target

Tags: android, android-source

I have an application in `packages/apps` under my vendor dir in Android O.
The application relies on a HIDL interface, which is added as a java library.

If I build the app with `Android.mk` file, it builds just fine.
If I build the app with `Android.bp` file, hiding the `Android.mk`, it doesn't build and fails with an error:

> ninja: error: unknown target 'MODULES-IN-vendor-${vendor_name}-apps-${app_name}', did you mean 'MODULES-IN-vendor-${vendor_name}-apps-${another_app_name}'?

Or it can be just

> ninja: error: unknown target 'MODULES-IN-vendor-${vendor_name}-apps-${app_name}'

My `Android.bp` looks like:

```
android_app {

    java_libs: ["some.hidl.lib-V1.0-java"],

    java_static_libs: ["android.hidl.base-V1.0-java-static"],

    srcs: ["**/*.java"],

    android_resource_dirs: ["res/**"],

    name: "MyApplication",

    module_name: "MyApplication",

    package_name: "me.myself.MyApplication", // also tried just the name as it is done in Android.mk

    enabled: true,

    proguard_enabled: disabled

}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you have resolved this issue, I also met such issue. This is caused by Android only tries to include the "Android.bp" file from the level 3 folder which is defined in "Android.bp" under root folder:

```
optional_subdirs = [
    ....
    "vendor/*/*",
]
```

So you need to add one "Android.bp" into vendor/vendor_name/packages with specified optional_subdirs or just wildcard as above.

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work for me. Still getting `unknow target`.

Comment: What's the content of your Android.bp? Just for your case, your Android.bp might be like: subdirs = ["apps/app_name"]. And build system will try to search Android.bp in your app_name folder

Comment: as in Android10, you don't need to explicitly add the `optional_subdirs` in `Android.bp` in AOSP root directory.

"Soong finds all Android.bp and Blueprints files in the source tree, subdirs= and optional_subdirs= are obsolete and this file no longer needs a list of the top level directories that may contain Android.bp files."

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using **Android.mk** file only but by mistake I used *arm64* in

> LOCAL_MODULE_TARGET_ARCH := arm64

But I was building for x86_64 target. So I changed to

> LOCAL_MODULE_TARGET_ARCH := x86_64

And I worked. Might be this answer is not directly related to it but If someone would have done same mistake then it would help.